# The wrong word order

Tags: meaning-in-context

Today I read a piece of news in which a delivery man was invited by a young housewife into her room "进来吹空调" and which led to a dirty ending.

吹空调 is hard to understand, it might mean someone blows (perhaps it is one of the methods used by electricians to do cleaning)the air cooler, but in this context, the woman got the man in to enjoy the coolness of the a/c, so the subject should be 空调, not the man, and the word order is apparently wrong.

Comment: https://www.zhihu.com/question/19649757/answer/15337307

Answer (score 3):

It's an idiomatic usage. 吹空调 means 被空调吹.

A similar usage in 吹风. For example, 我们出去吹吹风. You are not going to blow the wind, but wind blows you.

So, relying on the context, 吹... could mean either 让...吹 or 吹... .

For example,

meaning '让...吹'in those phrases: 吹空调; 吹风扇; 吹风;

meaning '吹...' in those phrases: 吹头发； 吹号； 吹气球；

Answer (score 2):

After some search, I found a terminology which describes this: [施事宾语](http://open.xrtvu.com/rpx/hyxx/Downloads/04/main01-02-03-02.htm).

> ②施事宾语
> 　　施事宾语是发出动作或行为的主体，或者是存现、消失的主体。
> 　　述语与施事宾语之间常用动态助词或补语。
> 　　　　下雨了。
> 　　　　出太阳了。
> 　　　　跑了两只羊。
> 　　　　来了一个警察。
> 　　　　这一锅饭能吃五个人。
> 　　　　这座桥可以过大卡车。
> 　　　　死了一位中毒严重的患者。
> 　　施事宾语一般可以转化为施事主语。上面的句子可以变换为：
> 　　　　雨下了。
> 　　　　太阳出来了。
> 　　　　两只羊跑了。
> 　　　　一个警察来了。
> 　　　　五个人能吃这一锅饭。
> 　　　　大卡车可以过这座桥。
> 　　　　一位中毒严重的患者死了。

Where the object is what does the action.

In this [Wikipedia Page](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%BF%B0%E8%B3%93%E7%9F%AD%E8%AA%9E), you can see the object can serve various relations to the verb:

> 述宾短语的成分在语义上是支配或关涉的关系。所谓的支配、关涉，其意义相当广泛。
>
> - 承受动作。例：“打|麻将”“喝|酒”
> - 动作的产物、结果。例：“写|硬笔字”“(这本书)卖|三块钱”（主语“这本书”承受动作，“三块钱”是动作的结果）
> - 事物的存缺。例：“没有|钱”“坐满|人”
> - 使动（尤见于古文中，现多以兼语短语表示）。例：“跑|狗、跑|马”“先破泰入咸阳者王|之。”“惊|天地，泣|鬼神”
> - 工具、方式。例：“写|毛笔”
> - 处所。例：“游|花园”“出|国”
> - **施事。例：“走出来了|两个人”**
> - 判断。例：“是|统一的国家”
>
> 以上只是支配或关涉的关系的例子。事实上，从按语义上的分类，把所有述、宾之间的关系全部举出来，是没有一定的准则。例如可是把宾语分类为施事、受事和当事（即不能归入前两类者）。上面所举出的各种关系只是大略的分类，以显示出支配或关涉的关系之广泛。

And this may not be a complete list.

Answer (score 0):

Think like it's like Yodish.

E.g.:
"When 900 hundred years old you reach, look as good you will not."

进来吹空调 -> come in and enjoy the AC -> come on it and chilling